# É seguro confiar a segurança de uma aplicação ao Spring Security?

Tags: spring, ejb, spring-security

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema razoavelmente simples porem bastante distribuído que envolve inclusive uso de EJBs e outros agentes, que exige tanto Autenticação como Autorização.

O sistema será composto inicialmente por Spring+Hibernate+JSF+JBoss, estarei usando inicialmente para o processo de identificação e autorização o [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)

É seguro confiar exclusivamente neste Framework? O que devo evitar ou Observar para evitar surpresas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delfino, você quer ter certeza de que ao escolher o Spring Security para Autenticação e Autorização, não terá problemas no futuro.

A resposta é: o o Spring Security pode atender perfeitamente suas necessidades, não sendo necessário por nenhum motivo usar JAAS diretamente. Você pode confiar nele.

Fiz várias pesquisas procurando comparações entre Spring Security e JAAS, e descobri que ambos são excelentes em suas propostas, o Spring, oferencendo uma excelente taglib.

Aqui está um link da documentação  oficial do Spring Security para integração com JSF:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-faces.html

Quanto a surpresas é difícil dizer, pois pode depender muito do tipo de aplicação que voce estará construindo, não existem Frameworks perfeitos, sempre podem haver melhorias, novos recursos, e bugs em *todos os frameworks*. Recomendo que de uma olhada nos Issues.

**Issues**:

Também dei uma olhada nos Issues mais críticos correntes no desenvolvimento do Spring Security, de uma olhada:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel

**Tips and Tricks para Spring Security**

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/spring-security-3-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, desculpe a demora em confirmar sua resposta, estava envolvido em outro projeto em outra linguagem.